# Java Concurrency

Tags: java, multithreading, hashmap, concurrenthashmap

I'm trying to implement some kind of accumulation logic in a multi threaded environment; I’m wondering is there any better/faster way to do it without the lock and synchronized keyword? The following is my current code:

```
public class ConcurrentHashMapTest {

    private static final int NB_THREADS = 1_000;

    private final Map<String, Integer> cnts = new HashMap<>();

    private static final Lock RWLOCK = new ReentrantLock(true);

    private static final String[] NAMES = {
        "A", "B"
    };

    public void testIt() {
        ExecutorService executor =
            Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NB_THREADS);
        for (int i = 0; i < NB_THREADS; i++) {
            Runnable task = new WorkerThread();
            executor.submit(task);
        }
        executor.shutdown();
        try {
            executor.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
        System.out.println(cnts);
    }

    private void accumulate(String name) {
        RWLOCK.lock();
        try {
            Integer cnt = cnts.get(name);
            if (cnt == null) {
                cnts.put(name, 1);
            } else {
                cnts.put(name, cnt + 1);
            }
        } finally {
            RWLOCK.unlock();
        }
    }

    private class WorkerThread implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            accumulate(NAMES[ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, NAMES.length)]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to have a look at guava multiset : https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained

Comment: Define *"better"*. About *"faster"*, do not optimize prematurely. Only if you see it is the real bottleneck of your program performance, then think how to do it faster.

Comment: I understand that, each thread will only call accumulate method, on which you have taken lock. It kills multi threading.

Comment: Your `testIt` method is not thread-safe. It's not enough that `cnts` is protected by the `RWLOCK` during modifications; it must also be protected during _all_ reads, including the `System.out.println(cnts)` in `testIt`. That is, you need to lock, print `cnts`, then unlock.

Comment: Doesn't it only print `cnts` after all worker threads have terminated? Actually, it looks like that's the intent, but it could do it then, or after a timeout (if they haven't finished); the latter could be a problem.

Comment: @yshavit testIt method is init method for the test and the main focus is accumulte method and David is right, it's just print out the accumulated count after all the worker threads have terminated

Comment: It could read half-written data, including in ways that make the HashMap break.

Comment: @yshavit The awaitTermination will hold the main thread and wait for all the worker threads to finish. Therefore, it won't print half-written data.

Comment: I understand that the worker threads will be finished, but that does _not_ mean that all of their affects are visible to all other threads. There could be instruction reorderings, for instance, or some of the memory that the worker thread changed might be cached in the CPU core that executed it. You need a formal happens-before relationship (JLS 17.4.5), which `awaitTermination` does not provide. Otherwise, you have a data race, and pretty much all bets are off.

Comment: @yshavit: if it is visible to the thread invoking `awaitTermination` that all tasks have been completed (which is the defined purpose of this method) all actions performed by these actions should be visible too. The only mistake is that the code here proceeds even when catching an `InterruptedException` as in this case it is not guaranteed that all tasks have been completed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Java 8:**

```
private final Map<String, AtomicInteger> cnts =
        new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

private void accumulate(String name) {
    cnts.computeIfAbsent(name, k -> new AtomicInteger()).incrementAndGet();
}
```

The `ConcurrentHashMap` can be freely accessed from multiple threads. The `computeIfAbsent` method takes a lambda to evaluate to get a value for the key if the key is not present in the map, and adds it if and only if there is no such mapping, and then returns that value. It's effectively `putIfAbsent` followed by `get`. The value is a new `AtomicInteger` with the value 0. Whether there was an existing value, or whether a new one with value 0 was just added, in either case increment it.

**Java 7:**

```
private final ConcurrentMap<String, AtomicInteger> cnts =
        new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

private void accumulate(String name) {
    cnts.putIfAbsent(name, new AtomicInteger());
    cnts.get(name).incrementAndGet();
}
```

For Java 7, there is no `computeIfAbsent` method, but that effectively just does a `putIfAbsent` followed by a `get`, so the same effect is achieved by calling those methods. There is no concern that the value already existed in the map; a new, zero `AtomicInteger` is added if and only if the map had no value for that key. Even if another thread got in there before us and added a zero, both threads would then see and increment that same `AtomicInteger` instance.

Comment: Your suggestion really neat and now I can remove the try and finally block.

Comment: Another improvement that can be considered is:

**Java 8:**

`private final Map<String, LongAdder> countsMap = new HashMap<>();`
And in accumulate method we have:
`countsMap.computeIfAbsent(name, k -> new LongAdder()).increment();`
The expected throughput of this class is significantly higher under high contention, at the expense of higher space consumption.

Answer (score 1):

use a concurrent hash map with String and AtomicInteger. Both are thread safe and thus can be used freely.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be wary of using fairness on your ReentrantLock in this case, as there's no benefit to your accumulator if longer waiting threads get access first. Take a look at Brian Goetz's 'Java Concurrency in Practice'

> Why wouldn't we want to make all locks fair? After all, fairness is good and unfairness is bad, right? (It's not accidental that whenever kids want to appeal a decision, "that's not fair" almost certainly comes up. We think fairness is pretty important, and they know it.) In reality, the fairness guarantee for locks is a very strong one, and comes at a significant performance cost. The bookkeeping and synchronization required to ensure fairness mean that contended fair locks will have much lower throughput than unfair locks. As a default, you should set fair to false unless it is critical to the correctness of your algorithm that threads be serviced in exactly the order they queued up.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `Map` of name to `AtomicInteger` and use double-check locking when there is no counter in the map at all. Be aware that you need to use the `volatile` keyword for effective double-check locking.

This way you will only lock the whole map for actually adding brand new entries, the rest of the processing can happen in parallel.

You risk massively over-complicating your program here though and possibly even reducing performance in real-world cases. Is contention on this map really a performance bottle-neck?

Comment: Or even a ConcurrentHashMap of AtomicIntegers, and use the putIfAbsent() method to create new zeroed entries in the map

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is a `Multiton`:

```
/**
 * Holds a thread-safe map of unique create-once items.
 *
 * Contract:
 *
 * Only one object will be made for each key presented.
 *
 * Thread safe.
 *
 * @author OldCurmudgeon
 * @param <K>
 * @param <V>
 */
public class Multiton<K, V> {

    // Map from the key to the futures of the items.
    private final ConcurrentMap<K, Future<V>> multitons = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    // The creator can create an item of type V.
    private final Creator<K, V> creator;

    public Multiton(Creator<K, V> creator) {
        this.creator = creator;
    }

    /**
     * There can be only one.
     *
     * Use a FutureTask to do the creation to ensure only one construction.
     *
     * @param key
     * @return
     * @throws InterruptedException
     * @throws ExecutionException
     */
    public V get(final K key) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        // Already made?
        Future<V> f = multitons.get(key);
        if (f == null) {
            // Plan the future but do not create as yet.
            FutureTask<V> ft = new FutureTask<>(() -> creator.create(key));
            // Store it.
            f = multitons.putIfAbsent(key, ft);
            if (f == null) {
                // It was successfully stored - it is the first (and only)
                f = ft;
                // Make it happen.
                ft.run();
            }
        }
        // Wait for it to finish construction and return the constructed.
        return f.get();
    }

    /**
     * Returns a Map indicating the current state.
     *
     * @return a Map which should reflect the current state.
     *
     * @throws java.lang.InterruptedException
     * @throws java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException
     */
    public Map<K, V> getMap() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        Map<K, V> map = new HashMap<>();
        for (Map.Entry<K, Future<V>> e : multitons.entrySet()) {
            map.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue().get());
        }
        return map;
    }

    /**
     * User provides one of these to do the construction.
     *
     * @param <K>
     * @param <V>
     */
    public abstract static class Creator<K, V> {

        // Return a new item under the key.
        abstract V create(K key) throws ExecutionException;

    }

}
```

Usage - for demonstration - adds up all integers up to 999, keying on their first digit:

```
Multiton<String, AtomicInteger> counts = new Multiton<>(
        new Creator<String, AtomicInteger>() {

            @Override
            AtomicInteger create(String key) throws ExecutionException {
                return new AtomicInteger();
            }
        }
);

public void test() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        counts.get(Integer.toString(i).substring(0, 1)).addAndGet(i);
    }
    System.out.println(counts.getMap());
}
```

Prints:

```
{0=0, 1=15096, 2=25197, 3=35298, 4=45399, 5=55500, 6=65601, 7=75702, 8=85803, 9=95904}
```

Java < 8 version:

```
/**
 * Holds a thread-safe map of unique create-once items.
 *
 * Contract:
 *
 * Only one object will be made for each key presented.
 *
 * Thread safe.
 *
 * @author OldCurmudgeon
 * @param <K>
 * @param <V>
 */
public class Multiton<K, V> {

  // Map from the key to the futures of the items.
  private final ConcurrentMap<K, Future<V>> multitons = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
  // The creator can create an item of type V.
  private final Creator<K, V> creator;

  public Multiton(Creator<K, V> creator) {
    this.creator = creator;
  }

  /**
   * There can be only one.
   *
   * Use a FutureTask to do the creation to ensure only one construction.
   *
   * @param key
   * @return
   * @throws InterruptedException
   * @throws ExecutionException
   */
  public V get(final K key) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    // Already made?
    Future<V> f = multitons.get(key);
    if (f == null) {
      // Plan the future but do not create as yet.
      FutureTask<V> ft = new FutureTask<>(new Callable<V>() {

        @Override
        public V call() throws Exception {
          // Doing this inline may be a little contrived but it maintains the linkage with the Java-8 version.
          return creator.create(key);
        }

      }
      );
      // Store it.
      f = multitons.putIfAbsent(key, ft);
      if (f == null) {
        // It was successfully stored - it is the first (and only)
        f = ft;
        // Make it happen.
        ft.run();
      }
    }
    // Wait for it to finish construction and return the constructed.
    return f.get();
  }

  /**
   * Returns a Map indicating the current state.
   *
   * @return a Map which should reflect the current state.
   *
   * @throws java.lang.InterruptedException
   * @throws java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException
   */
  public Map<K, V> getMap() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
      Map<K, V> map = new HashMap<>();
      for (Map.Entry<K, Future<V>> e : multitons.entrySet()) {
          map.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue().get());
      }
      return map;
  }

  /**
   * User provides one of these to do the construction.
   *
   * @param <K>
   * @param <V>
   */
  public abstract static class Creator<K, V> {

    // Return a new item under the key.
    abstract V create(K key) throws ExecutionException;

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Oracle Java 7 API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) : implementation of HashMap is not synchronized.

You can use `Hashtable` implementation or declare : `private final Map<String, Integer> cnts = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<String, Integer>());`

Comment: Synchronization doesn't help here, since you need to A) get the value for a key, if any, and B) put a 1 if it was missing, or C) add 1 to the value and put it back if it was present. `Hashtable` and `synchronizedMap` only synchronize each individual step, but don't synchronize between them. (Another thread could add a value in between the steps.) This is exactly why `Hashtable` was deprecated, and why the OP is using a `ReentrantLock` to begin with.